# How to filter data using IQueryable into a NHibernate DynamicJsonType Mapping

Tags: c#, json, nhibernate, iqueryable

I'm saving a `list` of  `Json` into a `varchar` on my data base

```
[
   {
      "Id":37,
      "Name":"John",
      "Departament":{
         "Name":"Criminal Justice",
         "Id":12
      }
   },
]
```

`NHibernate` works well on save and update as Mapped like this:

```
       Map(x => x.Competencias)
            .CustomType<DynamicJsonType<IEnumerable<Competencias>>>()
            .CustomSqlType($"NVARCHAR({int.MaxValue})")
            .Length(int.MaxValue)
            .Column("competencia_jurisdicao");
```

The problem occures over filtering:

SearchParam`class` Param

```
public class SearchParam
{
    public int? IdFunction{ get; set; }        

    public string Endpoint { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<CompetenciaDTO> Competencias { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost("searchByFilters")]
    public IList<ResponseDTO> SearchByFilters([FromServices] Paginator<Function> paginator, [FromBody] SearchParam filter = null)
    {
        using (UnitOfWork.BeginReadOnlyTransaction())
        {
            var query = Repository.FindAll<Function>();
            var limit = 0;
            var offset = 0;

            if (filter != null)
            {

                if (filter.Competencias != null)
                {
                    foreach (var competencia in filter.Competencias)
                    {

                        query = query.Where(o => o.Competencias.All(c => c.Id == competencia.Id));
                    }
                }
            }

            var total = query.Count();
            return paginator.Split(query, limit, offset, total, HttpContext)
            .AdaptToType<IList<ResponseDTO>>(); 
         }
     }
```

`Nhibernate` builds up a query like this:

```
select (count(*)) as col_0_0_ 
  from dbo.mni_function  function0_ 
 where not (exists 
             (select function0_ .id 
                from dbo.mni_function function0_ 
                where not (function0_ .id = ?)
             )
            )
```

Comment: Just to understand it. You want to denormalize the whole collection of Competencias into a string column but then query over individual properties of Competencia? I'm afraid that database specific syntax to query inside json or xml columns are not part of the abstraction  of NHibernate. you would have to register a custom function or resort to sql in this case.

Comment: @Firo we solved it by  ` query = query.ToList().AsQueryable();` before applying the filter.

Comment: this is a bad idea. It will force NHibernate to load the whole table if all filters are applied afterwards. Otherwise it will break pagination when pages are applied before ToList()

Comment: @Firo I agree, this is a temp solution, pagination is ok,  anyway later on we gonna split competencias obj into a new table as we don wanna any procedure or function on db. tks man.